# Delete a div on a button click (changing id)

Tags: javascript

I'm generating div with class and id changing. They are all the same and each one has a delete button.
I want to delete the div in which the clicked button is. Each button as the id "delete_index" in a "past_experience_index" div. In fact, when i click on delete_2, i want past_experience_2 to be deleted.

I tried several things but it does not work...

Here is the PHP :

```
<div class="experiences_container">
    <?php 
    if (!empty($experiences)) {
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($experiences as $key) {
        ?>
            <div id="past_experience_<?=$index?>" class="past_experience">
                <div class="experience_header">
                    <div>
                        <label for="team">Nom de l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="team" name="team_<?= $index ?>" value="<?= $key['team-name'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="role">Rôle dans l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="role" name="role_<?= $index ?>" value="<?= $key['team-role'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="experience_textarea">
                    <label for="description">Description du rôle</label>
                    <textarea class="description" name="description_<?= $index ?>"><?= $key['team-description']; ?></textarea>

                    <label for="palmares">Palmarés avec l'équipe</label>
                    <textarea class="palmares" name="palmares_<?= $index ?>"><?= $key['team-palmares']; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <p id="delete_<?=$index?>" class="delete_button">supprimer</p>
            </div>  
        <?php
        $index++;
        } 
    } else {
    ?>
    <div><p>Vous n'avez encore rentré aucune expérience</p></div>
    <?php 
}?>
</div>
```

So as a JavaScript beginner, i tried a for() with the php index value limit but it doesn't work. The $("div").remove(past_experience_index) works, but i can't have the actual index.

Thanks a lot

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs in the browser. If you want to do something by PHP it has to be invoked by JS first. There is no "LINK" between those two systems until you tell them for example by AJAX to interact. You may do things on the website first in JS and then send the result of those actions to php. Which will then process things on the SERVER and send the result back to the BROWSER. They do not talk directly to each others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an onclick function on button click pass $index as a function argument.

```
<p id="delete_<?=$index?>" class="delete_button" onclick="del_div_fun('<?php echo $index ?>')">supprimer</p>
```

Now you have to define this function in javascript like.

```
function del_div_fun(index_val){
var div_id = 'past_experience_'+index_val;
$('#'+div_id).remove();
  }//end of function del_div_fun
```

Please use jquery library

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jquery you don't really need to worry about ids. You can use jQuery to find the parent and remove it that way.

Something like this:

```js
$(".delete-btn").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding:10%;background-color:lightgrey;text-align:center;">
    <p style="cursor:pointer;" class="delete-btn">Delete</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need to duplicate indexes everywhere.

And you can avoid adding jquery into your page.

```js
<script>
    function deletePastExperience() {
        var experiencesContainer = document.querySelector('.experiences_container');
        var elementToRemove = document.getElementById(event.target.parentElement.id);
        experiencesContainer.removeChild(elementToRemove);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<p onclick="deletePastExperience()" class="delete_button">supprimer</p>
```